# Cómo mostrar dos listas en una vista por medio de un solo objeto

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Tengo una vista en mi proyecto de ASP, donde debo mostrar tanto los datos de una lista `tours` como de una lista `productos`, mi idea es crear una clase allí junto las dos listas, pero cuando le paso que los valores no los retorna bien la clase que cree los manda nulos, y no se cómo podría solcuionarlo.

Ésta es la clase que creé para tener ambas listas:

```csharp
public class listasFacturacion
{
    public static List<Tours> tour = new List<Tours>();

    public static List<Producto> producto = new List<Producto>();
}
```

Ésta es mi API, hasta aquí todo funciona correctamente; recibo ambas listas en las `listasFacturacion`.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("facturacion")]
public class FacturacionController : Controller
{
    public listasFacturacion listasFacturacion = new listasFacturacion();

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("listafacturacion")]
    public IActionResult ListaFacturacion()
    {
        listasFacturacion.tour = Almacenamiento.tours;
        listasFacturacion.producto = Almacenamiento.productos;
        return Ok(listasFacturacion);
    }

}
```

Pero aquí está el problema:

```
public async Task<listasFacturacion> ListasFacturacion()
{
    listasFacturacion listasFacturacion = new listasFacturacion();
    var cliente = new HttpClient();
    cliente.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);

    var respuesta = await cliente.GetAsync($"facturacion/listafacturacion");

    if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json_respuesta = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<listasFacturacion>(json_respuesta);
        listasFacturacion = resultado;
    }
    return listasFacturacion;
}
```

`DeserializeObject`, la instancia viene nula , las listas las reinicia pero la API sí retorna la instancia con las listas llenas de la clase `listasFacturacion`, pero no sé como lo podría solucionar.

Comment: Estás usando mal el concepto de ViewModel. Si recién estás aprendiendo sobre MVC, te sugiero este workshop que hice años atrás, los mismos conceptos se aplican a nuevas versiones: https://youtu.be/6LZG76aLykY Saludos.

Comment: gracias lo vere amigigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ApiController]
[Route("facturacion")]
public class FacturacionController : Controller
{
    // Esto se mueve de aquí:
    // public listasFacturacion listasFacturacion = new listasFacturacion(); 

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("listafacturacion")]
    public IActionResult ListaFacturacion()
    {
        // Para esta ubicación:
        listasFacturacion listasFacturacion = new listasFacturacion();
        listasFacturacion.tour = Almacenamiento.tours;
        listasFacturacion.producto = Almacenamiento.productos;
        return Ok(listasFacturacion);
    }

}
```

Ahora sí, cada vez que hagas una llamada, se creará una nueva instancia del modelo llamando los datos que tengas en `Almacenamiento`.

Comment: pero una duda el problema no esta en que creo una instancia del objeto listasFactuacion dos veces, una en la api donde tu me marcaste que estaba el error, y otra en el metodo que deserializa el objeto que viene de la api ?

Comment: En ese caso, edita la pregunta y agrega más información, por ejemplo, ¿de dónde viene `Almacenamiento` y qué datos trae cuando haces debugging?